# Chrome Devtools console hides all messages from remote device

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, ios-webkit-debug-proxy

I'm debugging an IOS iPad running Safari from Chrome Devtools on Linux using ios-webkit-debug-proxy and remotedebug-ios-webkit adapter.

It connects, and I can view the DOM etc, but console.log() messages do not show in the console.  I can see the hidden message count increase, but I can not find a way to view the messages.

It was working initially, but has stopped.  I have tried resetting devtools to default via "Settings->Preferences->Devtools->Restore defaults and reload", but no luck.

Please see the screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of chrome devtools]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've exactly the same problem, but on Windows. It shows how many are hidden and also the source in the sidebar, but I can do whatever I want. The hidden messages don't appear. The most interesting thing is that errors count towards the hiddden items, but each error displays a 2 px high red banner like it displays the error, but without any text and a height of 2 px.

Comment: I hit this wall as well and I can't find any bug reports on the Chromium bug tracker so I'm not sure if this is by design or a bug.  The only solution I came up with is to replace the console.debug() calls with a custom method that stores the messages in an observable and displays them in a DIV that I can minimize within the app.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the other answer, `console.info` appears to work in place of the standard `console.log`.

If you run `console.log = console.info;` before you log anything, it will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by making changes in `onConsoleMessageAdded` function in file `ios.ts`

Updated piece of code

```
let message = msg.params.message;
    let type;
    let method = "Runtime.consoleAPICalled";
    if(message.type === "log") {
        switch(message.level) {
                case "log": type = "log"; break;
                case "info": type = "info"; break;
                case "error": type = "error"; break;
                default: type = "log";
        }
    } else {
        type = message.type;
    }

    const consoleMessage = {
        source: message.source,
        level: type,
        text: message.text,
        lineNumber: message.line,
        timestamp: (new Date).getTime(),
        url: message.url,
        stackTrace: message.stackTrace ? {
            callFrames: message.stackTrace
        } : undefined,
        args:message.parameters,
        networkRequestId: message.networkRequestId,
    };
    if(type == "error"){
        method = "Log.entryAdded"; 
        this._target.fireEventToTools(method, {entry:consoleMessage});
    }else
        this._target.fireEventToTools(method, consoleMessage);
    
    return Promise.resolve(null);
}
```

Comment: This solution is actually solved the problem.
It would be better if he also mention the location of the file.

Comment: In my case the file is located at `C:\Users\[YOURNAME]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter\out\protocols\ios\ios.js`

Answer (score -1):

You can use console.error instead of console.log.

Comment: Downvoted because this solution doesn't help, see comment on the OP from @schl3ck